# Who knows about Helena?

Tags: orphan-black

Helena has been shown interacting with Sarah, Alison, their respective families, Cosima, Art, the Proletheans and Project Castor.  Veera (MK) probably knows at least some of her story.

Olivier met Helena, but may not have recognized that she was another rogue clone; and anyway he died without telling anyone the truth about the encounter.

So.  Does anyone at Dyad or Neolution – Aldus, Rachel, Delphine, Evie, Susan – know Helena exists?

How about Scott?  Alison's neighbors?  Vic or Angela?

Comment: In [here](http://orphanblack.wikia.com/wiki/Helena), there is a description of the character and a list of how many people she has interacted with.

Comment: 1x08, Delphine reading Cosima's chart to Aldous: _Helena. There is no last name._ This is when Delphine learns of Helena, but Aldous already knew, claiming in 1x09: _I've searched for the lost clone, Helena, for years. She's my white whale, Paul._ Then Rachel mentions Helena in 1x10: _We're not the enemy. Helena and her ilk are and we are going to help with that._ I'd wager that most high-ranking Dyad/Topside/Neolution players know of her.